# How to create a nested array with dynamic number of nesting levels that is assigned data on creation?

Tags: php

Currently I create the following nested array:

```
$data = // data from DB
$nested_array = [];
$counter = 0;

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $nested_array[$row->a][$row->b][$row->c]['id'] = $counter++;
}
```

In the above case I know the amount of nesting levels I want to use, i.e. `a,b,c`, which are some columns selected from the data

But I want to create the array based on an array of columns that I get. For example if I get:

`$columns_selected = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];`

then the nested array should be:

```
$nested_array[$row->a][$row->b][$row->c][$row->d][$row->e]['id'] = $counter++;
```

Answer (score 1):

evil-ish references in an assigner function could work, something like

```php
function assigner(array &$arr, array $keys, $value = null, bool $onlyFetch = false){
    $target = &$arr;
    foreach($keys as $key){
        $target = &$target[$key];
    }
    $originalValue = $target;
    if(!$onlyFetch){
        $target = $value;
    }
    return $originalValue;
}
```

now doing

```php
assigner($nested_array, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','id'], "test");
```

does the same as writing

```php
$nested_array["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"]["e"]["id"] = "test";
```

3v4l example: https://3v4l.org/#live

Comment: thank you! I will try it now. But I think I will need to do some changes because in my case the final nesting level is a string (`id`), whereas the others are columns from the db (`$row->x`). I might just edit the function with `if` condition for the final key or some sort (and pass the `$data` array)

Comment: @Stackerito could add id to the columns array before giving it to assigner, like ```assigner($nested_array, [...$columns_selected, "id"], $value);``` - or you could alter the last line to be ```$target["id"] = $value;``` - then your assigner function will only be able to write the "id" property though.

Comment: I will give both a try, but notice that the keys are the column names which I need to access the data they correspond to, so I will also probably need to pass the currently iterated `$row` from the main `foreach` so that I can access the data as seen in the question (maybe something like `$target = &$target[$row->$key];`)

Comment: @Stackerito hmm well the original function didn't return anything, might as well return the original value, and make setting a new value optional. code updated.

Comment: thank you, I edited your answer just to show you what I mean, you don't have to use it, I just wanted to explain it in code. And it's working btw